# jQuery ui Draggable with <select> tag

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

With select tag draggable does not work. What can I do with this?

```
<div id="draggable">
    <select style="width: 200px;">
    </select>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#draggable').draggable();
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wrqLwyk6/2/

Comment: A little better https://jsfiddle.net/wrqLwyk6/9/

Answer (score 2):

This may help you

HTML:

```
 <ul id="draggable">
 <li>
   <select  style="width: 200px;">
   <option>56456456456</option>
   <option>sdfsdf</option>
  </select>
  </li>
 <ul>
```

CSS:

```
#draggable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#draggable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; cursor:move; }
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#draggable').draggable();
});
```

Check at : https://jsfiddle.net/759td80m/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `<div>` is draggable, but you should actually click and drag on the `<div>` itself, not the `<select>`. Almost all of the form controls like `<textarea>` blocks dragging in similar way. To test this, just add a background color or something to `<div>` and drag the remaining area to the right of `<select>`.

But users wouldn't be aware of this invisible area (if there is any). It is to handle such situations we have the [**`handle`**](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle) option:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#draggable').draggable({
    handle: '.handle'
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable .handle {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable">
  <span class="handle"></span>
  <select style="width: 200px;">
  </select>
</div>
```

In the demo, click and drag the blue box which is used as handle.

Comment: It is will be my fallback plan. But I still want keep it simple.